# Check two form fields

Tags: javascript

hi
i want two check two fields 
if the value of two fields is same then its shows a message two me i have a code but

its not working can you tell me what worng with this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkForm(form1){
    if(form1.field1.value == form1.field2.value ){
        alert(" values are identical");
        form1.field1.focus();
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="" >
<input type="text" name="field1">
<input type="text" name="field2">
<input type="submit" onClick="return checkform1(this);" >
</form>
```

Comment: For starters, you're calling `checkform1` and your function is named `checkForm`.

Answer (score 4):

Change your if condition like this

```
if(document.form1.field1.value==document.form1.field2.value)
```

Comment: remove this from function when you are calling it at onclick event of your button

Comment: and also you are calling function checkform1 at onclick event of your submit button. But you have defined function as checkForm. Make the form name similar when you are calling. It is also your spelling mistake

Comment: thanks buddycan you tell me one more thing i already used the

Comment: jquerry can we use more then one script a time or not

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `checkform()`, but that's not defined anywhere. Also, `checkform1(this)` uses the button as the element `form1`, which screws everything up. Use `this.parentNode`, which passes the form as the argument.

Here's some working code:

```
<script>
    function checkForm(form1) {
    if (form1.field1.value == form1.field2.value) {
        alert(" values are identical");
        form1.field1.focus();
        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
</script>

<form name="form1" method="POST" action="" >
    <input type="text" name="field1">
    <input type="text" name="field2">
    <input type="submit" onClick="return checkForm(this.parentNode);" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `document.` in front of your form selections. And your method name is wrong from the method you are calling from your click event.

I've fixed it and included an example here : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/Fu2wJ/1/

```
function checkForm(form1) {
    if (document.form1.field1.value == document.form1.field2.value) {
        alert(" values are identical");
        document.form1.field1.focus();
        return false;


    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
<form  name="form1" method="POST" action="" >
    <input type="text" name="field1">
    <input type="text" name="field2">
    <input type="submit" onClick="return checkForm();" >
</form>
```

Comment: The reason he doesn't use `document.` is he (thinks) he is passing that in as a parameter. See Blender's answer.

Comment: ohhh. I didn't notice (this) being passed. That would make sense. I'll remove the `this` reference from my answer for clarity

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that `checkForm1` function does not exist , the main problem lies in

`<input type="submit" onClick="return checkform1(this);" >`

Here the `this` refers to the `input` and not the `form`.

To make your code working change the function name to `checkForm` and

`<input type="submit" onClick="return checkform1(this.form);" >`